# Reset Linux password using web form (PHP)

Tags: php, linux, forms, passwords, reset

I have a Linux server (Fedora 18 with Linux kernel 3.6.10) that has VSFTP and Apache running on it that my friends sometimes use to host files.  I'm trying to make a PHP form that they can use to change their passwords without logging into the actual server using SSH or something.

I've got a form that asks for your username, current password, new password, and retype new password, but I can't figure out what to call to verify the username/password combination, or to actually change the password.

I've been getting familiar with Linux lately, but haven't used shell_exec before.  Looking around the internet it sounds like I need to parse out /etc/shadow to verify the password, which isn't hard, but I'm not sure what encryption to use on the input password to match it against shadow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Such a script can seriously compromise the security of your server! What is the reason for your friends having system user accounts on the server in the first place? If it's for FTP you can configure your server to auth FTP users using MYSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Create a shell script to handle the password verification and change, and then use PHP to call that shell script.

The password is stored in /etc/shadow as a md5sum. You have to do a md5sum on the entry and compare it to the corresponding entry in /etc/shadow to verify.

Example implementation can be found [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/change-linux-or-unix-system-password-using-php-script.html).

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to create a bash script that uses the `passwd` command which accepts parameters input from the web form such as username and password.  Here is a link which shows one example of how to do that:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/change-linux-or-unix-system-password-using-php-script.html